# Ford Fulkerson.. what is the purpose of the backwards edge?

Tags: algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I'm learning about the Ford Fulkerson algorithm and I'm confused by the purpose of the backwards edges, and how they help us reach a maximum flow. I've watched a couple different videos and read some documentation on the algorithm but nothing is clicking. Perhaps someone here can put it in a way that will make sense to me!

Comment: Perhaps you mean the edges which have their capacity increased when you increase the flow over a path. They allow us to partially "undo" the flow we selected if our selection turns out to be non-optimal. That is, increasing the flow along such an edge actually decreases the flow along the corresponding forward edge which we chose previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gassa's comment is correct. Here is a simple example.

Suppose you have a source S, a sink T, and two intermediate nodes A and B, and paths from S to A and A to T, and from S to B and B to T of capacity 1.

```
  A
 / \
S   T
 \ /
  B
```

Obviously there is a flow of weight 2 using each edge. Now, add an edge from A to B of capacity 1.

```
  A
 /|\
S V T
 \|/
  B
```

This doesn't increase the maximum flow, but it gives you a chance to mess up when you create a flow incrementally. You could start with S->A->B->T.

```
  A
 /|
S V T
  |/
  B
```

In order to find the maximum flow, you need to be able to decrease the flow from A to B. You can do this by increasing the flow along S->B->A->T.

```
  A         A         A
 /|         |\       / \
S V T  +  S ^ T  =  S   T
  |/       \|        \ /
  B         B         B
```

Going backwards along A->B means you decrease the flow from A to B.